# Routing not happening in iron-router

Tags: meteor

```
I have updated meteor project to 0.8.0 and have installed iron-router package. Did everything that is required but routing not happening. It is showing the front page i.e I am able to login into the application. But after that not able to go to any of the pages. My homepage have so many buttons as can be seen in header.html file. When I clicked on grumble link, in url it is displaying that "localhost:3000/grumble". But nothing is getting displayed on that form.
```

-->    My router.js page is:

```
Router.configure({

    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('issues', {path:'/'});
    this.route('issues', {path:'/issues'});
    this.route('closedIssues', {path:'/closedIssues'});
    this.route('subscribedKeywords', {path:'/subscribedKeywords'});
    //this.route('grumble');
    //this.route('grumble2');

    this.route('grumble', {path:'grumble'});
    this.route('grumble2', {path:'grumble2'});

    this.route('issuePage', {

        path:'/issues/:_id',
        data: function() {Session.set('currentIssueId', this.params); }
    });

    this.route('closedIssuePage', {

        path:'/closedIssues/:_id',
        data: function() { Session.set('currentClosedIssueId', this.params); }
    });
});


var requireLogin = function() {
    if ( Meteor.user()) 
        this.render(this.params);
    else if (Meteor.loggingIn())
        this.render('loading');
    else
        this.render('accessDenied');


        this.stop();

}

var clearErrors = function() {
    clearErrors();
    this.render(this.params);

    this.stop();

} 

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'grumble'});
Router.onBeforeAction(clearErrors);
```

-->    Header.html file is from where grumble.html has been called meas href is present in this page to transfer the control:

```
<template name="header">
    <header class="navbar">
    <p>inside header.html</p>
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-coll
        apse">
            </a>
            <a class="details btn" href="{{pathFor 'grumble'}}">Grumble</a>
            {{#if currentUser}}
                    <a class="details btn" href="{{issuesPath}}">See Issues</a>
                    <a class="details btn" href="{{closedIssuesPath}}">Closed Issues</a>
                    <a class="details btn" href="{{subscribedKeywordsPath}}">Watchlist</a>
                    {{> notifications}}

            {{/if}}
            <span class="nav pull-right">
                <li>{{> loginButtons}}</li>   <!--should be {{> }} here in order to display login functionality-->
            </span>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>
```

-->    Grumble.html, the file to which control should be transferred means routing has been done for this page to get the control

```
<template name="grumble">
<p>inside form i.e. grumble.html</p>
    <form class="main">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>New Grumble</legend>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="shortdesc"><span style="color:red;">*</span>&nbsp;    Description</label>
                            <input name="shortdesc" type="text" value="" placeholder="Radiator not working"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="urgency">Urgency</label>
                            <select name="urgency" >
                                <option value="high">High</option>
                                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                <option value="low">Low</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
                            <input name="date" type="date" value="{{date}}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="time">Time</label>
                            <input name="time" type="time" value="{{time}}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="dept">Department/Building</label>
                            <input name="dept" type="text" value="" placeholder="Physiotherapy"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="unit">Unit</label>
                            <input name="unit" type="text" value="" placeholder="Occupational Therapy"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="room">Room</label>
                            <input name="room" type="text" value="" placeholder="P2"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="category">Category</label>
                            <input name="category" type="text" value="" placeholder="Utility"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="details">Details</label>
                            <textarea name="details" value="" placeholder="Broken radiator next to vending      machine."></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="control-label" for="anonymous">Anonymity</label>
                            <select name="anonymous" >
                                <option value="anonymous">Anonymous</option>
                                <option value="identifiable">Identifiable</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </template> 

<template name="grumble2">
    <form class="main">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>New Grumble</legend>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="control-label" for="details"><span style="color:red;">*</span>&nbsp;Description</label>
                        <textarea name="details" value="" placeholder="Broken radiator next to vending machine."></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</template>

Please help me where I am wrong as have read the article : http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial. And tried to make changes but not working. Any pointers please.
```

Comment: What do you get in your web browser's error console (not the terminal window). Also your `clearErrors();` looks like it might have an infinite loop in it since you call it when you run it

Comment: Even after commenting the lines related to clearErrors(), still getting same problem. I just read that {{renderPage}} is not there in iron-router. So, it might be possible that it (renderPage) is not letting these pages to come. If yes, then what should be there in place of {{renderPage}} or if this is not the problem, then what else should be done.

Comment: {{renderPage}} is from Meteor router not for iron-router. Could you list the packages you are using

Answer (score 0):

I think the route `this.route('issues', {path:'/issues'});` overwrites the route `this.route('issues', {path:'/'});` (they have the same name!), so you have no route for `/`. Try changing name on one of them, and see if that makes a different.

Comment: I have commented out one b/w them. Still the same problem, in url, it is showing the url but not actually going to the page as I removed pages from the project folder and did not get any error. I think it is not able to search the particular .html page in the project. But why it is so. Any pointers

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a "/" in front of your grumble route path. It should be `this.route('grumble', {path:'/grumble'})`